# IE8 Iframe Same Domain Doesn't Load

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

Running on

```
http://localhost:8081
```

There is an iframe in the markup that points to another page on the same domain.

```
<iframe src="/OtherPage/#SomeAjaxResource"><iframe>
```

Some of the dom on this iframe needs to be manipulated to isolate an inner portion of the content (since the src url is accessible externally as it's own page as well)

The frame src loads fine if there is no hash value on the iframe, but if there is a hash value in the src for the frame or even just a # on the end of the iframe src url, the frame fails to load (the url is not even requested according to Fiddler), and there are no errors reported by IE. All of this works fine in Chrome, obviously.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: `http://localhost:8081,` ???

Comment: Did you try `/OtherPage#SomeAjaxResource` ?

Comment: Yes, anything that has a # in it at all doesn't load. Even if it's just /OtherPage#

Comment: why is that comma at `http://localhost:8081,` ?

Comment: I wrote the URL as part of a sentence first, it's just grammar for the question.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the # ????

Comment: If the iframe page didn't need it to load the correct ajax content, I would happily remove it. It shouldn't be an issue though since the browser doesn't even send hash content to the server.